# CloudHSM login/logout error

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm

So i was trying to login/logout from AWS CloudHSM multiple times. The flow is the following:

1. Have an open session (`C_GetSessionInfo` returns slot id 1, state 3, flags 6 while everything goes fine).
2. If i'm logged in to this session, call `C_Logout` on this session.
3. Call `C_Login` supplying the correct credentials.
4. Repeat.

After the first login, the first logout/login cycle goes fine but during the second logout a `CKR_DEVICE_REMOVED` error is returned and every subsequent calls return `CKR_SESSION_HANDLE_INVALID`.

Calling `C_GetSessionInfo` after the error returns slot id, state and flags all set to 0 and `C_GetSlotList` with token present returns an empty list. This behavior (error on the second logout) is completely consistent and happens every single time. No operations are performed while being logged in.

Does anyone know the possible reason for this error and how to avoid it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need not logout each time when you do some operation. The best way is: You should re-use the session handle id which you got when you login for the first time.